# Why does my light switch have 2 wires on the top?

Tags: electrical, switch, light

I went to change my light switch to a new touch light switch I ordered and for some reason it has 2 wires on top. I googled this and searched for awhile but nothing came up about this topic and all I saw was people having 2 wires on bottom instead.

[image]

Comment: turn the switch upside down and you will have two wires on the bottom

Comment: Based on your question, I would highly recommend that you hire a professional to replace the switch.

Comment: they're on top because you're holding it sideways.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this is because one wire is supplying the power and the other wire is tied into  it in order to take the power on to be used elsewhere.

Another way this is accomplished is that the two wires, plus a third "a pig tail" are all tied together with a wire nut and the pig tail goes to the switch.

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that one of the wires is providing electric power and the other wire is the destination of the power (**device**: lighting, etc.).  The purpose of the switch is to electrically connect the device per the user command.

I applaud the question because not everyone understands what happens (electrically) within in a switch, however, if this is new to you or unclear, then it is important to have a professional with experience to work with wiring for safety reasons.